# How to remove header from frontmatter

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have a header created with `fancyhdr`. It repeats on all the pages including Table of Contents and Preface sections. I tried to use `\thispagestyle{empty}` but it only works on the first page while I need to clear it in the `frontmatter`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}

\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1.5pt}
\makeatletter
\def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
        \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth
        \vskip 2pt% 2pt between lines
        \hrule\@height.5pt\@width\headwidth% lower line with .5pt line width
        \vskip-\headrulewidth
        \vskip-1.5pt}}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\frontmatter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Table of contents

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\mainmatter
\chapter{Ch1}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\lipsum
\section{test}
\chapter{ch2}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\end {document}
```

Comment: Do you really want empty style or only roman page numbers, without rules?

Comment: @Bernard I am still not sure about the standard, what if I want to remove the chapter title and numbering from the header, while keeping the lines...

Answer (score 7):

change this one

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

to

```
\pagestyle{empty}
```

and insert \pagestyle{fancy} here

```
\mainmatter
\chapter{Ch1}
```

It will looks now like

```
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{Ch1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you'want? In front matter, there's only chapter title (Contents/Preface), first chapter pages and white pages have empty style (for the whole document). I added the `twoside` option, and used the `emptypage` and `xpatche` packages to achieve that.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xpatch, emptypage}%
 \pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}

\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1.5pt}
\makeatletter
\def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
        \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth
        \vskip 2pt% 2pt between lines
        \hrule\@height.5pt\@width\headwidth% lower line with .5pt line width
        \vskip-\headrulewidth
        \vskip-1.5pt}}
\makeatother

%%
\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{%
\thispagestyle{plain}}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Table of contents
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Preface}
\markboth{Preface}{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\lipsum
\lipsum[1-4]
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{Ch1}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\lipsum
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{ch2}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\lipsum
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\end {document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]