# How to remove page number from the first page of ToC, LoT, LoF?

Tags: page-numbering

I am having a problem with the Table of Contents, List of Tables, and List of Figures. What I want is that ToC, LoT and LoF should not have roman page numbers on the first page. All three of them will be several pages long, and page numbers should appear from the second pages, onwards.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{Thesis}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,justification=justified,format=plain]{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,backgrounds,calc,fit,positioning,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\setbiblabelwidth{1000}
\newcites{lop}{List of Publications}
\hyphenation{arti-ficial draw-back para-meters relati-onships rev-erse}
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=black,colorlinks=false} 

\thesistitle{MY TITLE}

\degree{DOCTOR OF PHILOSOPHY (TECHNOLOGY)}

\degreemajor{MY SUBJECT}

\authors{MY NAME}

\university{MY UNIVERSITY}

\department{MY DEPARTMENT}

\semsub{2019}

\title{\ttitle} 

\begin{document}

\frontmatter 

\setstretch{1.6} 

\fancyhead{}

\rhead{\thepage}

\lhead{}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\hypersetup{pdftitle={\ttitle}}
\hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}

\maketitle

\clearpage

\setstretch{1.3} 

\pagestyle{empty}

\dedicatory{
    \Huge{
        \textit{
            \calligra
            Dedicated to my loving parents
        }
    }
}

%\setstretch{1.3}

\acknowledgements{\addtocontents{toc}{}

Acknowledgements...

}

\clearpage

\addtotoc{Abstract}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\abstract{
    \addtocontents{toc}{}

    Abstract...

}

\clearpage

{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}

\lhead{\emph{Contents}}

\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\emph{List of Figures}}

\listoffigures 


\lhead{\emph{List of Tables}}

\listoftables

\clearpage

\setstretch{1.5}

\lhead{\emph{Abbreviations}}

\listofsymbols{ll}
{
    \textbf{FN} & \textbf{F}alse \textbf{N}egative \\
    \textbf{FP} & \textbf{F}alse \textbf{P}ositive \\
    \textbf{GNW} & \textbf{G}ene\textbf{N}et\textbf{W}eaver \\
    \textbf{GRN} & \textbf{G}ene \textbf{R}egulatory \textbf{N}etworks \\
    \textbf{HS} & \textbf{H}alf-\textbf{S}ystem \\
    \textbf{RNN} & \textbf{R}ecurrent Neural Network \\
    \textbf{SS} & \textbf{S}-\textbf{S}ystem \\
    \textbf{TN} & \textbf{T}rue \textbf{N}egative \\
    \textbf{TP} & \textbf{T}rue \textbf{P}ositive
}

\mainmatter

\setlength{\parindent}{30pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\input{Chapters/Chapter1}
\input{Chapters/Chapter2} 
\input{Chapters/Chapter3} 
\input{Chapters/Chapter4} 
\input{Chapters/Chapter5}
\input{Chapters/Chapter6}
\input{Chapters/Chapter7}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{3em}}

\backmatter

\nocite{*}

\label{bib}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}}

\setstretch{1.3}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{ieeeref}

\clearpage

\label{lop}

\lhead{\emph{List of Publications}}
\setstretch{1.3}

\bibliographystylelop{IEEEtran}

\bibliographylop{lop}

\nocitelop{*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a full compilable code? We don't even know what's your document class

Comment: The document class is thesis. It is a class file I have got from my peers. It can be found at https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/indian-institute-of-technology-kharagpur-(iit-kgp)-thesis-template

Comment: I have solved the problem partially by adding \tocloft in the class file and \tocloftpagestyle{empty} before \begin{document} as suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226038/no-page-numbering-on-toc-lot-lof?rq=1. However, the problem remains for the List of Abbreviations. Also, the ToC, LoT, and LoF appear in the contents with incorrect page numbers (i.e. one page after). Somebody, please help!

Comment: Thank you, Bernard! Your answer to the question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313486/how-to-remove-header-from-frontmatter solved my problem. Thank you, very much!

Comment: You're welcome. I completely had forgotten this one!

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem has been very elegantly solved by Bernard in the following thread: [How to remove header from frontmatter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313486/how-to-remove-header-from-frontmatter)